# How to get multiselected Dropdownlist values in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem to get multi select dropdown list values.can anyone suggest me how to get select multiple dropdownlist values as well as how to get them in controller.

My code is like this:-

**Model**

```
public string BusinessUnitSiteSafetyRepresentative { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddClientBusinessUnitSite(LocalAddClientBusinessUnitSite local)
{
 var query = from o in entitydb.systemusersorganizations.toList()
             from c in entitydb.contacts.toList()
             where o.orgId == clientId 
             select new SelectListItem
             {
                Text = c. Name;
                Value = c.OrgId.toString()                 
             }
 ViewBag.list1 = query.ToList();
}
```

Well, I can get if single value is selected & can save to DB.But how to select multiple values as well as to get them in Controller so as to save them.

Note: - I am retrieving the dropdownlist values from DB as shown above.

**View**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => Model.BusinessUnitSiteSafetyRepresentative,new 
 MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@Viewbag.list1)
```

I have gone through some examples but none of them helped me.Please help me.

Comment: _"none of them helped me.Please help me."_ with _what_? You didn't show what happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I am saying that Examples I have gone through not helped me. I mean even selecting multiple values also not working for me even though i use ListBoxFor..

Comment: _"not working"_ is also not helpful. What code did you use, what happened and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What I suggest is that your model needs to have a one to many relationship with the items in your multi select list.

An example is a Blog with multiple tags:

Your blog model may look like:

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public string BlogTitle{ get; set; }
    public string Body{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags{ get; set; }
}
```

And your tag model like so:

```
    public int TagID{ get; set; }
    public string TagName{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs{ get; set; }
```

Now I recommend you use a view model:

```
public class BlogViewModel
{
    public Blog blog{ get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedTags { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> Tags{ get; set; }

    public BlogViewModel()
    {

    }

    public BlogViewModel(Blog _blog, List<Tag> _Tags)
    {
        blog = _blog;
        Tags = _Tags;
        SelectedTags = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

And finally in your View (which inherits from the ViewModel);

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags,
new MultiSelectList(Model.Tags, "TagID", "Tag")
, null)
```

The JQuery Chosen plugin is excellent for this http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/.  You can use it by:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags,
new MultiSelectList(Model.Tags, "TagID", "Tag")
, new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Tags..." })
```

Replace this with your own model and controllers and this should solve your problem.  Also, this will work in your form for creating a new blog post, and for editing an existing post (adding and removing tags)

edit:

In your Blog Create controller action, you would populate this as:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var blog = new Blog();
        var AllTags = from t in db.Tags
                           select t;
        BlogViewModel viewModel = new BlogViewModel(blog,
            Tags.ToList());

        return View(viewModel);

    }

    public ActionResult Create(BlogViewModel blogViewModel)
    {
        Blog blog = blogViewModel.blog;

        if (blogViewModel.SelectedTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var TagID in blogViewModel.SelectedTags)
            {
                Tag tag = db.Tags.Where(t => t.TagID == TagID).First();
                blog.Tags.Add(tag);
            }
        }
        db.Blog.Add(blog);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. how to get the selected values in controller??

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a create method which shows how you would find which values were selected

Comment: Thats great. Thank you but i found a simple solution ..thanks

Comment: Admittedly since I posted this though I've moved from Chosen to Select2 - same principle but I find the performance better

Answer (score 5):

Try to change your modelproperty to a list type to accept multiple values:

```
public IEnumerable<string> BusinessUnitSiteSafetyRepresentative { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answer by EvoNet. Its a different approach but worked well for me.

Here is Microsofts official way to do it: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Search for:
A join table is required in the database, however, as shown in the following database diagram:

I tried it and yes it created the table but I had to start editing the controller to get it to write to the table. Then I also had to think about creating cases for when a relationship already exists etc.

So I reveted to this method which worked just fine for me.