# ASP.NET MVC ListBox does not show the selected list items

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I am in a big trouble. I read 4 stackoverflow question and one blogpost. I have tried 5 different approach to view the selected items in a multiple selectlist.

I have no success.

The multiple selectlist is generated, but it does not select the items. I have no more idea.

**Model**:

```
public class EditableModel
{
     public IList<Company> SelectedCompanies { get; set; }
     public IList<SelectListItem> SelectListCompanies { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     var service = _serviceDAL.GetEditableModel(id);

     if (service!= null)
     {
          service.SelectListCompanies = GetSelectListCompanies(service.SelectedCompanies);
          return View(service);
     }
}

private IList<SelectListItem> GetSelectListCompanies(IList<Company> selectedCompanies)
{
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Companycompany in _companyService.GetCompanies())
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = company.CompanyId.ToString(),
                Text = company.Name,
                Selected = selectedCompanies.Any(x => x.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)
            });
        }
        return items;
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.ListBox("SelectedCompanies", Model.SelectListCompanies, Model.SelectedCompanies.Select(x => x.CompanyId.ToString()) )
```

And nothing. The items in the select list is not selected...

I have tried this [Multiselect](http://www.mitechdev.com/2016/04/multi-select-dropdown-in-mvc5.html), the same result, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428638/asp-net-mvc-listboxfor-multiselectlist-does-not-apply-the-selected-item) as the current solution.

Comment: have you verified what is in selectedCompanies? With just this it appears, to me, that selectedCompanies is empty.

Comment: @Dabagab did you try to use ListBox with "Model.SelectListCompanies as MultiSelectList" I mean @Html.ListBox("SelectedCompanies", Model.SelectListCompanies as MultiSelectList, Model.SelectedCompanies.Select(x => x.CompanyId.ToString()) )

Comment: @MaCron It was not empyt. It had 11 items. I debuged it :)

Comment: @hsnbl. I have tried the Listbox, but nothing happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects. It binds to, and posts back an array of simple values (the values of the selected options).

Your `SelectedCompanies` property needs to be `IEnumerable<int>` (assuming the `CompanyId` of `Company` is also `int`). Note also the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when binding to a property.

Your also using the same collection for the selected Companies and the list of all Companies which makes no sense. Your `SelectListCompanies` should be generated from your table of `Company`.

Model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public IEnumerable<int> SelectedCompanies { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListCompanies { get; set; }
}
```

Base on your current code for `EditableModel`, your code should be

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var service = _serviceDAL.GetEditableModel(id);
    ....
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel
    {
        SelectedCompanies = service.SelectedCompanies.Select(x => x.CompanyId),
        SelectListCompanies = GetSelectListCompanies()
    };
    return View(model);

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListCompanies()
{
    var all companies = ... // call method to get all Companies
    return companies.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.CompanyId.ToString(),
        Text = x.Name
    });
}
```

However, it look like you should be modifying your `EditableModel` and the `GetEditableModel()` code to return the correct data in the first place.