# How to retrieve selected values from multiselect list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<h2>My Chart</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.ListBox("chosen")
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#chosen").select2(
        {
            placeholder: "Choose States ",
            width:300
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my script for making my multiselect dropdown, it works. I want to collect these values and store them in an array or list which i can use in my controller but i have no idea how to do that.

this is my controller method for populating the list

```
public ActionResult Charter()
{
    ViewBag.chosen = new MultiSelectList(_mydb.States,"Id","Name");

    return View();
}
```

This is my model

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Stations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021978/how-to-get-multiselected-dropdownlist-values-in-asp-net-mvc/17023462#17023462

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Charter(State[] states)
{
    //here type logic

    return View();
}
```

or try this one:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Charter(int[] ids) // also you can try like this: **IList<int> ids**
{
    //here type logic

    return View();
}
```