# There is multiple datavaluefield of dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a single dropdownlist in which i selected 2 values(i.e progid,courseid) from database, now how can i add those values in datavaluefield of dropdownlist in code behind, i now that at a time there is only single value come in datavaluefield but i want multiple datavaluefield?

Comment: Unless you are willing to store them both in one string then parse them back out as needed, you will probably want to consider a different control - like ListView or GridView. Also, client-side templating frameworks like Angularjs support binding javascript objects. But if you are not doing any of that already it would probably be a prohibitive amount of refactoring.

Comment: can you give me the answer of this question                                                                 http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/643737/how-to-bind-multiple-value-in-dropdownlist-from-th

Comment: The solutions given in that link are basically what I just said - concatenate the values you want into one string then parse them back to separate values when you need them.

Comment: i don't know if you're using razor (mvc) or web forms, but if you want to create the multiselect with preselected values (the values you have loaded from the database) you can do it using ListBoxFor helper passing the MultiSelectList, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021978/how-to-get-multiselected-dropdownlist-values-in-asp-net-mvc)