# ASP.NET MVC5 Razor ListBox in Form with MultiSelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, listbox

I am trying to have a ListBox where one can select multiple Tags for a Quote that is beeing created in the Form. Everything is rendered fine, all options that should be shown are shown in the ListBox, but even though I selected some, the corresponding Collection in the returned ViewModel is empty or null.

I simplified the model for the sake of my question and it basically only has Quotes with a many-to-many relationship to Tags. So, when I want to create a new Quote I have to give it Content and a Collection of Tags.

So I have a model like this:

```
public class Quote
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; private set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Tag
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Designation { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; private set; }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class QuoteCreateViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Quote Quote { get; set; }

    public QuoteCreateViewModel(Quote quote, IList<Tag> tags)
    {
        Quote = quote;
        Tags = tags;
    }
}
```

QuotesController:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        QuoteCreateViewModel viewModel =
            new QuoteCreateViewModel(new Quote(), _context.Tags.ToList());

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(QuoteCreateViewModel quoteCreateViewModel)
    {
        Quote quote = quoteCreateViewModel.Quote;

        _context.Quotes.Add(quote);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

And the corresponding View:

```
@model CiteMe.ViewModels.QuoteCreateViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Quotes"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quote.Content)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quote.Content, new { @class = "form-control"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quote.Tags)
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Quote.Tags, new MultiSelectList(Model.Tags, "Id", "Designation"), new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

As far as I am concerned `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Quote.Tags, new MultiSelectList(Model.Tags, "Id", "Designation"), new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })` should do the trick for me. I have also tried an approach I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17023462/6585358), but it delivers the same results. Empty Collections even though something was selected or null instead of an instance of the Collection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my mistake in the implementation of this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17023462/6585358).

The type of the Collection has to be the type of the id property, which I screwed up.

In the ViewModel I had a property of type `List<Tag>` instead of `List<typeOf(Tag.Id)>`.