# Bind selected item in multiple select .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have this query to get the data inserted in my db

```cs
var groups = (from group_s in _context.Groups
              select new SelectListItem()
              {
                 Text = group_s.GroupName,
                 Value = group_s.GroupId.ToString(),
              }).ToList();
ViewBag.Groups = groups;
```

and this my html select tag

```
<select class="select2 form-control" 
        asp-for="@Model.Group" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Groups,"Value", "Text"))" 
        multiple>
</select>
```

my problem is how to get the items selected in my form, please someone have any idea ?

Comment: See if following post is helpful. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021978/how-to-get-multiselected-dropdownlist-values-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following.

**View Page**

```
@model Core_Web_App_MVC.Controllers.MyGroupModel

<form method="post">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedGroups, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Groups, "Value", "Text"), null)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Controller Code**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Core_Web_App_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class MyGroupModel
    {
        public List<int> SelectedGroups { get; set; }
    }
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> groups = new List<SelectListItem>();
            groups.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Group 1", Value = "1" });
            groups.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Group 2", Value = "2" });
            groups.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Group 3", Value = "3" });
            ViewBag.Groups = groups;

            MyGroupModel myGroupModel = new MyGroupModel();
            myGroupModel.SelectedGroups = new List<int>();

            return View(myGroupModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(MyGroupModel data)
        {
            return View(data);
        }
    }
}
```